# 1950s TV episode where a motorcyclist takes a drug which changes his time perception, enabling him to avoid logs falling off a truck

Tags: story-identification, tv

On a show like *Science Fiction Theater* (but not that one), a maniac was releasing logs from the back of his truck and killing motorcycle riders. A man took a drug which changed his time perception, such that he could react in time to avoid the logs as they were released, so he could catch the truck and its driver.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

This is "[The Dropper](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0640977/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)", an episode of *[The Man and the Challenge](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0131178/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)*

> A homicidal maniac had his trunk rigged so that logs were ejected to kill or injure motorcycle policemen pursuing him. George Nader devises a drug that slows reflexes and logs were able to be dogged and the killer finally apprehended.

Found with a search for `1950s tv show motorcyclist drug logs`

It can be viewed on YouTube (the logs are dropped about 21 minutes in):

Comment: "...a drug that slows reflexes ..."   wouldn't it be better to speed up reflexes?

Comment: @Pete Yeah, the episode actually says that it speeds up perception.